# C++ Builder + RESTRequest + Dreamfactory - cannot pass session_id HTTPHeader

Tags: c++, rest, http-headers, c++builder, builder

Using trial version of C++ Builder XE7 and the REST components.  I think I am not passing HTTPHeaders to Dreamfactory v1.8 correctly. I am able to authenticate with a POST request that requires an e-mail and password to be passed as a JSON object in the Body property.  I can get the session_id that I require for subsequent calls.

The RESTDebugger works super well and gets the data from the table as well - but I am unable to translate that into an application in C++. Here is my code from the event that is fired after I call the login resource

```
enter code here
void __fastcall TForm1::RESTRequest1AfterExecute(TCustomRESTRequest *Sender)
    {
    Label1->Text = RESTResponse1->JSONText;

    TJSONObject *JSON = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse1->JSONText);
    TJSONPair *pair = JSON->Get("session_id");
    sSessionID = pair->JsonValue->ToString();
    RESTRequest2->Resource = "mssql_utilities/leaveCategory?order=categoryname";
    RESTRequest2->Method = rmGET;
    RESTRequest2->AddParameter("X-DreamFactory-Application-Name", "NDTVi", pkHTTPHEADER);
    RESTRequest2->AddParameter("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", sSessionID, pkHTTPHEADER);
    RESTRequest2->AddParameter()
    RESTRequest2->Execute();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect that the RESTRequest2->AddParameter method is incorrect.  The RESTRequest2->Execute() returns HTTP 500 Server Error.

Am working on Windows 8.1 and can't get Fiddler 4 to work - so am unable to see what is getting passed to the server.

Please, please, help.  Need to get this working so I can purchase the license and start working on the project.

Many thanks

Iyer

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Turned out that I was passing an incorrect value for the session ID parameter from the first call.  This code worked.  I have used TWO RESTRequest objects. One authenticates with Dreamfactory and returns the session_id and RESTRequest2 is used to fetch the data - the session ID is passed as an HTTP header to Dreamfactory.

```
        TJSONObject *JSON = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse1->JSONText);
        TJSONPair *pair = JSON->Get("session_id");
        sSessionID = pair->Value();
        RESTRequest2->Resource = "mssql_utilities/leavecategory";
        RESTRequest2->Params->AddItem("X-DreamFactory-Application-Name", "myApp", pkHTTPHEADER);
        RESTRequest2->Params->AddItem("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", sSessionID, pkHTTPHEADER);
        RESTRequest2->Execute();
```